# Text width inside a table

Tags: tables, chess, textwidth

I'm using tables to format pages for a book with 6 chess positions for page. I'd like the positions to be aligned and it works fine if the text is short, but for positions where I have a longer sequence of moves, it throws off the table alignment. What I'd like to do is set a maximum width for the text so it will automatically go to a new line without disrupting the horizontal spacing, but the text width settings I've tried don't seem to apply inside of a table.

Good page (boards are aligned):

[image: Good page]

Bad page (longer sequences break the alignment):

[image: bad page]

Code sample:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{skak}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}

    \begin{tabular}{cc}

    
      \makecell{
      \textbf{ Analysis Position } 2014\\
      \textbf{ 1 }\chessboard[setfen= r1bqkb1r/pp3ppp/2n1pn2/2pp2B1/3P4/2P1PN2/PP1N1PPP/R2QKB1R b KQkq - 0 6, smallboard, showmover]\\
      \textbf{ 6...c4 }
      }
      
    
      \makecell{
      \textbf{ Uesugi - Perelshteyn } 2009\\
      \textbf{ 2 }\chessboard[setfen= r1r3k1/qp3pbp/p2p1np1/3Pp3/NP2P3/P2Q1BPP/5P2/R4RK1 w - - 0 19, smallboard, showmover]\\
      \textbf{ 19. g4 }
      }
      
      \vspace{0.25cm}
      \\
      
    
      \makecell{
      \textbf{ Perelshteyn - Onischuk } 2010\\
      \textbf{ 3 }\chessboard[setfen= r1bqk2r/pp4bp/2pp2p1/5pP1/2P2Nn1/2N1P3/PPQ2PP1/2KR1B1R w kq - 0 13, smallboard, showmover]\\
      \textbf{ 13. c5 d5 14. Ncxd5 cxd5 }
      }
      
    
      \makecell{
      \textbf{ Spassky - Petrosian } 1966\\
      \textbf{ 4 }\chessboard[setfen= 2kr3r/pbqnbp2/1p2p3/2ppP2p/PP3B1p/2PBPN2/5PP1/R2Q1RK1 b - - 0 17, smallboard, showmover]\\
      \textbf{ 17...c4 18. Be2 a6 }
      }
      
      \vspace{0.25cm}
      \\
      
    
      \makecell{
      \textbf{ Yang - Perelshteyn } 2010\\
      \textbf{ 5 }\chessboard[setfen= rnbq1rk1/5pbp/p2p1np1/2p5/1p1PP1P1/4BP2/PP1QN2P/R2NKB1R w KQ - 0 13, smallboard, showmover]\\
      \textbf{ 13. dxc5 dxc5 14. Qxd8 Rxd8 15. Bxc5 }
      }
      
    
      \makecell{
      \textbf{ Carlsen - Amonatov } 2018\\
      \textbf{ 6 }\chessboard[setfen= 1qr1rn2/1b1n1pbk/pBp3pp/Pp2p3/1PP1P3/3B1NNP/5PP1/R1QR2K1 w - - 0 24, smallboard, showmover]\\
      \textbf{ 24. c5 }
      }
      
      \end{tabular}
      \newpage
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the macro `\twoboards` with six parameters: title,boad,moves of left image and title,board,moves of right image.

We need not any tabular environment. Each `\twoboards` is `\centerline` with two objects `\singleboad`. These objects have fixed width 120pt and they are separated by `\hss\hss`. Because `\centerline` is `\hbox to\hsize{\hss #1\hss}` we get the first `\singeboard` centered in the left half of `\hsize` and second one in the right half.

Each `\singleboard` is `\vtop`, so they are vertically aligned by the first line, i.e. by the title. The internal parameters of `\vtop` is given: `\hsize=120pt` and `\leftskip`, `\rightskip` in order to have the last paragraph with moves centered to the given `\hsize`.

```
\def\twoboards#1#2#3#4#5#6{\par
   \centerline{\singleboard{#1}{#2}{#3}\hss\hss \singleboard{#4}{#5}{#6}}
   \bigskip
}
\def\singleboard#1#2#3{%
   \vtop{\hsize=120pt \leftskip=0pt plus1fil \rightskip=\leftskip \parfillskip=0pt 
      \centerline{\bf\ignorespaces #1\unskip}
      \vskip-8pt
      \centerline{\ignorespaces #2\unskip}
      \noindent\bf \ignorespaces #3\par}%
}

\twoboards
   { Analysis Position  2014 }
   { 1 \chessboard[setfen= r1bqkb1r/pp3ppp/2n1pn2/2pp2B1/3P4/2P1PN2/PP1N1PPP/R2QKB1R b KQkq - 0 6, smallboard, showmover] }
   { 6...c4 }
   %
   { Uesugi - Perelshteyn 200 }
   { 2 \chessboard[setfen= r1r3k1/qp3pbp/p2p1np1/3Pp3/NP2P3/P2Q1BPP/5P2/R4RK1 w - - 0 19, smallboard, showmover] }
   { 19. g4 }

\twoboards
   { Perelshteyn - Onischuk  2010 }
   { 3 \chessboard[setfen= r1bqk2r/pp4bp/2pp2p1/5pP1/2P2Nn1/2N1P3/PPQ2PP1/2KR1B1R w kq - 0 13, smallboard, showmover] }
   { 13. c5 d5 14. Ncxd5 cxd5 }
   %
   { Spassky - Petrosian  1966 }
   { 4 \chessboard[setfen= 2kr3r/pbqnbp2/1p2p3/2ppP2p/PP3B1p/2PBPN2/5PP1/R2Q1RK1 b - - 0 17, smallboard, showmover] }
   { 17...c4 18. Be2 a6 }

\twoboards
   { Yang - Perelshteyn  2010 }
   { 5 \chessboard[setfen= rnbq1rk1/5pbp/p2p1np1/2p5/1p1PP1P1/4BP2/PP1QN2P/R2NKB1R w KQ - 0 13, smallboard, showmover] }
   { 13. dxc5 dxc5 14.~Qxd8 Rxd8 15. Bxc5 }
   %
   { Carlsen - Amonatov  2018 }
   { 6 \chessboard[setfen= 1qr1rn2/1b1n1pbk/pBp3pp/Pp2p3/1PP1P3/3B1NNP/5PP1/R1QR2K1 w - - 0 24, smallboard, showmover] }
   { 24. c5 }
```

Everything we need to know to understand this solution is TeX primitive commands `\hbox`, `\vtop`, `\hss`, `\vskip` and TeX primitive registers `\hsize`, `\leftskip`, `\rightskip` and the macro `\centerline` commonly defined in all formats.

Comment: Great solution! Relieved to not need tables!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't properly set your `tabular` and `margins`. I define a new column type `P` which has fix width and center alignment. I set the margin to 2cm(top,bottom,left and right) and showed the page frame using `showframe` package. You content is now in the center of the page. If any cell have a longer content it will breakable and center aligned.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{skak}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\usepackage{makecell}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill{\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\makecell[{{P{6cm}}}]{
\textbf{ Analysis Position } 2014\\
\textbf{ 1 }\chessboard[setfen= r1bqkb1r/pp3ppp/2n1pn2/2pp2B1/3P4/2P1PN2/PP1N1PPP/R2QKB1R b KQkq - 0 6, smallboard, showmover]\\
\textbf{ 6...c4 }
}&
\makecell[{{P{6cm}}}]{
\textbf{ Uesugi - Perelshteyn } 2009\\
\textbf{ 2 }\chessboard[setfen= r1r3k1/qp3pbp/p2p1np1/3Pp3/NP2P3/P2Q1BPP/5P2/R4RK1 w - - 0 19, smallboard, showmover]\\
\textbf{ 19. g4 }
}\vspace{0.25cm}\\
\makecell[{{P{6cm}}}]{
\textbf{ Perelshteyn - Onischuk } 2010\\
\textbf{ 3 }\chessboard[setfen= r1bqk2r/pp4bp/2pp2p1/5pP1/2P2Nn1/2N1P3/PPQ2PP1/2KR1B1R w kq - 0 13, smallboard, showmover]\\
\textbf{ 13. c5 d5 14. Ncxd5 cxd5 }
}&
\makecell[{{P{6cm}}}]{
\textbf{ Spassky - Petrosian } 1966\\
\textbf{ 4 }\chessboard[setfen= 2kr3r/pbqnbp2/1p2p3/2ppP2p/PP3B1p/2PBPN2/5PP1/R2Q1RK1 b - - 0 17, smallboard, showmover]\\
\textbf{ 17...c4 18. Be2 a6 }
}\vspace{0.25cm}\\
\makecell[{{P{6cm}}}]{
\textbf{ Yang - Perelshteyn } 2010\\
\textbf{ 5 }\chessboard[setfen= rnbq1rk1/5pbp/p2p1np1/2p5/1p1PP1P1/4BP2/PP1QN2P/R2NKB1R w KQ - 0 13, smallboard, showmover]\\
\textbf{ 13. dxc5 dxc5 14. Qxd8 Rxd8 15. Bxc5 sdfsdfsdfs}
}&    
\makecell[{{P{6cm}}}]{
\textbf{ Carlsen - Amonatov } 2018\\
\textbf{ 6 }\chessboard[setfen= 1qr1rn2/1b1n1pbk/pBp3pp/Pp2p3/1PP1P3/3B1NNP/5PP1/R1QR2K1 w - - 0 24, smallboard, showmover]\\
\textbf{ 24. c5 }
}
\end{tabular}\par}\vfill
\end{document}
```

The ouput:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll get better control of the layout and alignment of the chessboards by using both columns of the table. (and less typing)

There are three rows for each game: the title, the chessboard, and the moves.

Both center and bold are in the definition of the columns. Added an optional new command  `\moves` to keep the width of moves close to that of the chessboard (15*8pt as defined by `skak`) if so desired.

Note the `~` used on the last row `14.~Qxd8` to avoid a lonely number in the line.

[image: d]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{skak}
\usepackage{chessboard}

%************************************ added
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{@{}>{\centering\bfseries\arraybackslash}p{0.5\linewidth}@{}}

\newcommand{\moves}[1]{% set the width of moves close to the chessboard 120pt
    \parbox[t]{120pt}{\centering #1}
    }   

%************************************

\begin{document}
\centering

\begin{tabular}{CC}
        
    Analysis Position  2014                         &   Uesugi - Perelshteyn 2009\\[-0.3cm]
    1 \chessboard[setfen= r1bqkb1r/pp3ppp/2n1pn2/2pp2B1/3P4/2P1PN2/PP1N1PPP/R2QKB1R b KQkq - 0 6, smallboard, showmover]&   
    2 \chessboard[setfen= r1r3k1/qp3pbp/p2p1np1/3Pp3/NP2P3/P2Q1BPP/5P2/R4RK1 w - - 0 19, smallboard, showmover]  \\ 
    \moves{ 6...c4 }                                &  \moves{ 19. g4 }\\[0.50cm]% add vertical space
    
    Perelshteyn - Onischuk  2010                    &    Spassky - Petrosian  1966\\[-0.3cm]
    3 \chessboard[setfen= r1bqk2r/pp4bp/2pp2p1/5pP1/2P2Nn1/2N1P3/PPQ2PP1/2KR1B1R w kq - 0 13, smallboard, showmover]&   
    4 \chessboard[setfen= 2kr3r/pbqnbp2/1p2p3/2ppP2p/PP3B1p/2PBPN2/5PP1/R2Q1RK1 b - - 0 17, smallboard, showmover] \\
    \moves{ 13. c5 d5 14. Ncxd5 cxd5 }              & \moves{ 17...c4 18. Be2 a6 }\\[0.70cm]% add vertical space
    
    Yang - Perelshteyn  2010                        &  Carlsen - Amonatov  2018\\[-0.3cm]
    5 \chessboard[setfen= rnbq1rk1/5pbp/p2p1np1/2p5/1p1PP1P1/4BP2/PP1QN2P/R2NKB1R w KQ - 0 13, smallboard, showmover]&
    6 \chessboard[setfen= 1qr1rn2/1b1n1pbk/pBp3pp/Pp2p3/1PP1P3/3B1NNP/5PP1/R1QR2K1 w - - 0 24, smallboard, showmover]\\
    \moves{ 13. dxc5 dxc5 14.~Qxd8 Rxd8 15. Bxc5}   &    \moves{ 24. c5 }   
    
\end{tabular}
```